# Conversion error parsing number formatted with a comma as the number group separator

Tags: c#, parsing, formatting

In mvc I have formatted a numeric value using a comma as the [number group separator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as is specified in the [Indian numbering system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system):

```
PaymentReceived = String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-IN", true), "{0:n}", t.PaymentReceived)
```

Later, I need to parse the string back to a numeric value.  Here the `FieldValue` is of type `long`, while the right side value is of type `string`. How do I get the conversion to `long`?

I already have tried to do he following, but this is throwing an error message (`the input string was not in correct format`):

```
FieldValue = Convert.ToInt64( String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-IN", true), "{0:n}", t1.FieldValue))
```

Comment: Why are you formatting the value and then converting it *back* to an `Int64`? What is the type of `PaymentReceived` to start with? (Formatting and then immediately parsing is almost always a bad idea - you can usually avoid using *any* string conversion in such cases.)

Comment: i am trying to get comma separated values .. so, i using string.format()..@JonSkeet

Comment: Well how do you expect a comma-separated value to be parsed by `Convert.ToInt64`? This whole question is very confusing, to be honest... we really need more information about the types and the data involved.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comment, you do not need to format a string with commas to convert it to a `long`. The commas are purely a presentation issue and None of the primitive number data types(int, long, double...) will maintain them.

To convert the string to long, do this.

```
FieldValue = Convert.ToInt64(t1.FieldValue)
```

To display the value as a comma separated number, do this

```
string formattedString = FieldValue.ToString("N0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with the number group separator in your string.  Your problem is that, when you formatted your number, you used the `"{0:n}"` format but did not specify a precision.  From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#NFormatString):

> If the precision specifier is omitted, the number of decimal places is defined by the current [NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimaldigits%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

For `"en-IN"` the default number of digits is 2.  Thus your number, despite being a long, is being formatted with decimal digits.  I.e. if you do:

```
        long val = 1111111011;
        var s = String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-IN", true), "{0:n0}", val);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
```

The result looks like `1,11,11,11,011.00`.

Later, you try to parse the string back to a `long` -- which throws a `FormatException`.  The string is in an invalid format for a `long` because it contains a decimal point while `long` can only have integer values.

To avoid this problem, you could:

1. Format the initial value without a decimal point by using a precision of zero:

   ```
   String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-IN", true), "{0:n0}", t.PaymentReceived)
   ```
2. Parse to decimal and round:

   ```
   (long)Math.Round(decimal.Parse(s, new CultureInfo("en-IN", t.PaymentReceived)));
   ```